# Parameter type confusing

Tags: dart, dart-io

i am trying to use VirtualDirectory class and find a great example in web.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';

main() {
    HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8888).then((HttpServer server) {
        var vd = new VirtualDirectory('./');
        vd.jailRoot = false;
        vd.serve(server);
    });
}
```

look at call method serve

```dart
vd.serve(server);
```

and the passed parameter, it is from httpserver type. But when i am looking in api docs it expected a httprequest type.

```dart
StreamSubscription<HttpRequest> serve(Stream<HttpRequest> requests)
Serve a Stream of HttpRequests, in this VirtualDirectory.
```

Why i can pass a httpserver instance to serve method instead httpreqeust instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation of HttpServer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpServer)

> The HttpServer is a Stream that provides HttpRequest objects.